# Config enviroment variables in Salesforce

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, variable, environment

in others language like PHP or NodeJs. I can use .env file to store enviroment variables. For example, I need to use one enviroment variable is API_URL

- Then in local:

```
API_URL will have a value of 'http:localhost:3000'
```

- In DEV:

```
API_URL will have a value of 'http:url_dev.com'
```

- In Production:

```
API_URL will have a value of 'http:url_production.com'
```

So I want to ask that in salesforce, is it possible to use enviroment variable like above example? If it can do, please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Which metadata do you want this capability to work with?

Answer (score 3):

There is a new feature in the Salesforce CLI version `7.176.1` documented in the release [notes](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/sfdx/README.md#71761-nov-10-2022-stable).

> Replace snippets of your metadata source files with specific values right before you deploy the files to an org with the `force:source:deploy|push` commands! Note works with only the force:source:deploy or push commands of the CLI

To create a replacement you will need a section named `replacements` in your `sfdx-project.json`

```
"replacements": [
 {
  "filename": "force-app/main/default/classes/myClass.cls",
  "stringToReplace": "replaceMe",
  "replaceWithEnv": "THE_REPLACEMENT"
  "replaceWhenEnv": [{
     "env": "DEPLOY_DESTINATION",
     "value": "PROD"
     }]  
 }
]
```

The above implied Replace **THE_REPLACEMENT** in the Apex class myClass with the string **replaceMe** when there is an environment variable named **DEPLOY_DESTINATION** with value **PROD**.

You can specify these keys in the replacements property:

**filename:** Single file that contains the string to be replaced.

**glob:** Collection of files that contain the string to be replaced. Example: **/classes/*.cls.

**stringToReplace:** The string to be replaced.

**regexToReplace:** Regular expression that specifies a string pattern to be replaced.

**replaceWithEnv:** Specifies that the string be replaced with the value of the environment variable.

**replaceWithFile:** Specifies that the string be replaced with the contents of a file.

**replaceWhenEnv:** Specifies a condition, using environment variables, for when a string replacement occurs.

Currently it does not support a file format of `.env` so you would need a true environment variable in your operating system.

Comment: Mohit, why i would do like this and not use Custom labels ? Becaz, In later case i will have to update labels for each environment ?